# Mixing Objective-C files in Swift Pod

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, dependencies, cocoapods

We are creating our private Pod in Swift and have to include some legacy code which is written in Objective-C. I was wondering what's the way to include that in our Pod and use it in swift files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the latest cocoapods it should just work. Include the Swift files and the Objective C files in the `source_files` for the spec and it will all compile together. You can't use a bridging header in a pod, but the Swift classes can access anything that's public in the umbrella header.

Comment: I just did this, I can see all objc & swift files in my Pod architecture, but still can't find the swift classes in my objc project.

Comment: oups, I just forgot to call `@import MyPod;`

Comment: yeah, importing helps. :)